# Duplicating items with android:

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-theme, android-styles

Trying to setup my app to use Material design:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

- If items with `android:` are removed - the colors are not getting applied.
- If items without `android:` are removed - app crashes:

`Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.foo.bar/com.foo.bar.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`

**Questions:**

- Why do I have to duplicate those?
- Should I duplicate all styles like that?

**EDIT:**

The Manifest file is:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.foo.bar">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

**EDIT2**

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tl_periods"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMinWidth="100dp"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
```

Comment: Please add your manifest file. What is your app theme ?

Comment: Are you setting a custom background/theme for your `TabLayout`?

Comment: @RohitRamkumar updated question description.

Comment: @JoshLaird yes, trying to do that as well. It also says that I am missing `selectableItemBackground`.

Comment: For the `Material` themes you should need the `android:` prefixes. This could be an error with your `TabLayout`. Could we see the XML for it and the theme you're trying to apply?

Comment: Can you post the layout XML file for the MainActivity. Looks like something is wrong in Line #9

Comment: Updated description with layout XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theme of your application is not a descendant of `AppCompat` theme, whereas your `TabLayout` is from support packages.

You either have to stick with `AppCompat` theme and views, or entirely be support packages independent, otherwise such nasty issues will rise.

Comment: I want to stick to API21+, use Material Design and get away from any support libraries as much as possible. What are my actions to resolve this?

Comment: Do you mean that `TabLayout` is defined in some other way in API21+? Should I drop `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` usage?

Comment: You are trying to use a widget, which is shipped with [support packages only](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html?q=tablayout). In particularly this case you'd better change your app style.

Comment: I would like to stick with Material design. How tabs are implemented in this case?

Comment: You think `AppCompat` is not material design? `AppCompat` theme is material design implementation for pre-lollipop devices, you are free to change your style.

Comment: Yes, but what Tabs do Lolipop+ devices use in this case? Does this mean there is no Lolipop+ tabs-widget and there is only `TabLayout` (which is pre-Lolipop and requires AppCompat)?

Comment: `TabLayout` is shipped with support design package, it is not shipped with API 21+. It is just a library that you have to include in your dependencies in order to use it.